# Change Properties of Buttons in an array in a loop

Tags: arrays, xcode, uibutton, nsmutablearray

im really new to programming but i don't get why the following xcode isn't working:

That's where i create the List of buttons:

```
self.btnlist[1] = self.ol ;
self.btnlist[2] = self.om ;
self.btnlist[3] = self.or ;
self.btnlist[4] = self.ml ;
self.btnlist[5] = self.mm ;
self.btnlist[6] = self.mr ;
self.btnlist[7] = self.ul ;
self.btnlist[8] = self.um ;
self.btnlist[9] = self.ur ;
```

And this is a button, which should run through the array

```
- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender {

for (int j=1;j<=9;j++){
    [[self.btnlist objectAtIndex:j] setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[self.btnlist objectAtIndex:j] setEnabled:true];

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are allocating the array.

```
self.btnlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In objective-c you can send a message to a null pointer without crashing the program. Which is exactly what you would be doing if you didn't allocate/init before you assigned those pointers.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer and sorry for bothering you with my obvious mistakes

Comment: @LukasSchmid Not a problem at all, we all do it. Welcome to SO, and if I solved your problem please check the box to accept the answer. In the future you can help combat nil pointers by using if() statements. Such as `if (!self.btnlist) self.btnlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`